# Raspberry pi 2 .start wifi on boot

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspberry-pi2

i have just bought a raspberry pi 2 . i manged to set up a headless setup by setting up an ip in the commandline.txt file and then connect to it via putty.
In the /etc/network/interfaces i set up a static ip for the wifi connection along with the connection name and password. and the wifi works fine...

But the problem is the raspberry pi wont connect to wifi unless i connect the ethernet cable and make one ssh connection using putty..

If i boot  using wifi only the green light  will not turn up and i am not sure if the raspberry  is booting or no...but when the ethernet is connected  the gren light  starts blinking  and i can  make an ssh connection.

can anyone  help  me with this.

Comment: that's strange... what wifi dongle do you have?

Comment: found this http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13558/how-to-get-wi-fi-to-connect-on-boot

Answer (score 0):

I've dealt with a lot of pi wifi issues.

Adding "auto wlan0" to /etc/network/interfaces helped, but there were still instances where it didn't start up. I have the edimax ew-7811un usb wifi adapter. Can't remember where I took this script from to give credit.

I have cron running this script (wifi_check.sh) every five minutes:

```
keepalive_host='ip to ping here'

ping -q -c1 $keepalive_host >> /dev/null

if [ "$?" -ne "0" ]; then
        ifdown wlan0
        rmmod 8192cu
        modprobe 8192cu
        ifup wlan0
fi
```

You could repurpose the script and have something like this in crontab

```
@reboot /bin/sleep 30 ; /path/to/wifi_check.sh
```

Which should wait 30 seconds after boot, try to ping the server you specify, if it can: do nothing, if it can't: bring the wifi connection down and then try to bring it back up. I don't think the lines with 8192cu in them are necessary for your purposes unless that driver is also used by your wifi adapter.